# How do I delete certain rows from a Core Data SQLite database?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I am an iOS development newbie. I want to delete a few rows from my Core Data SQLite database which have the attribute tagName = "F".

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: are you using core data or sqlite directly?  you tagged core-data but your question only refs sqlite.  Also, what have you tried?  What's your issue?  Do you want someone to write the delete code for you?

Comment: I am using coredata. I am not getting how to do that particular thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using core data, you shouldn't try and delete rows in the database. Rather, you delete the managed objects and save the context, and allow Core Data to do the rest.